# Как передать переменные окружения в команду poetry run script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pycharm, poetry

У меня есть сервис на Poetry.

```
import uvicorn
import os
from fastapi import FastAPI


app = FastAPI(title=os.getenv("APP_NAME", "app"))


def main() -> None:
    uvicorn.run(app, host=os.getenv("APP_HOST", "localhost"), port=os.getenv("APP_PORT", 8000))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

И я пытаюсь установить переменные окружения перед запуском, чтобы всё запустилось. Но не совсем понимаю как это правильно сделать.

Перед выполнением `poetry run main` пробовал установить переменные окружения с помощью `set KEY=val`, но это не сработало и их по прежнему не было видно в коде. То есть после `set APP_PORT=9000`, при запуске он по прежнему был 8000.

Попробовал устанавливать переменные так: `$env:APP_PORT="9000"`. Это уже сработало и код начал запускаться. Но порт 9000 должен быть интом (так говорится в сообщении об ошибке) и `$env:APP_PORT=9000` не помогает. А в коде на каждую переменную с интом кажется не очень удобным добавлять `port = int(os.getenv("APP_PORT", 8000))`.

Как можно правильно добавить переменные? Если я запускаю через PyCharm, то всё нормально работает. Как он устанавливает переменные окружения?

[image]

Comment: при задании APP_PORT=9000 через environment variables,  type(os.getenv("APP_PORT", 8000)) - str

Comment: `set KEY=val` — это команда для обычного cmd. Если вы пытаетесь выполнять эту команду в PowerShell, то это псевдоним для `Set-Variable -Name KEY=val` и таким образом вы создаёте переменную с названием `KEY=val` (да, val тоже становится частью названия) и пустым значением. Если вместо PowerShell вы запустите обычный cmd, то `set APP_PORT=9000` должно в нём заработать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если `$env:APP_PORT="9000"` помогает передать переменную внутрь окружения `poetry` (насколько мне подсказывает гугл, это способ для powershell), то его и используете.

Также можно установить плагин [`poetry-dotenv-plugin`](https://github.com/mpeteuil/poetry-dotenv-plugin) для `poetry`:

```
poetry self add poetry-dotenv-plugin
```

тогда можно будет не устанавливать переменные окружения вручную, а прописать их в `.env` файле, что-то типа

```
APP_NAME=application
APP_HOST=0.0.0.0
APP_PORT=9000
```

Этот вариант удобен, если нужно указать несколько значений.

---

По второй части: переменные окружения всегда хранят строки. Если нужно получить число, вам конкретное значение нужно конвертировать в число, и способ через `int(os.getenv("APP_PORT", 8000))`, который вы упоминаете,- вполне рабочий вариант.

Если не нравится оборачивание в `int()`, например, можно использовать пакет [pydantic-settings](https://pypi.org/project/pydantic-settings/) ([документация](https://docs.pydantic.dev/dev/concepts/pydantic_settings/)), в модели описать поля, их типы, дефолтные значения. При наличии соответствующих значений в переменных окружения они заменят значения по умолчанию, при этом значения сконвертируются в соответствии с аннотациями типа в модели.

Пример:

```
from pydantic_settings import BaseSettings


class Settings(BaseSettings):
    app_name: str = "app"
    app_host: str = "localhost"
    app_port: int = 8000


settings = Settings()

print(settings)
print(type(settings.app_port))
# app = FastAPI(title=settings.app_name)


def main():
    ...
    # uvicorn.run(app, host=settings.app_host, port=settings.app_port)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Вывод при запуске без записи в переменные окружения:

```
> python test.py
app_name='app' app_host='localhost' app_port=8000
<class 'int'>
```

Вывод с передачей значения через переменную окружения (запускаю на linux):

```
> env APP_PORT=9876 python test.py
app_name='app' app_host='localhost' app_port=9876
<class 'int'>
```

Кроме переменных окружения поддерживаются `.env` файлы, см. там же: [Dotenv (.env) support](https://docs.pydantic.dev/dev/concepts/pydantic_settings/#dotenv-env-support), это будет работать и без установки плагина `poetry-dotenv-plugin`.

Comment: @andreymal, по поводу дополнения согласен, откатил вопрос. Ответ дополнил.

Comment: «это способ для powershell» — это кстати объясняет почему `set KEY=val` не сработало (написал в комментарии к вопросу)